# Spring Cloud custom Enable* annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations, cloud

i want to learn how the Enable* Annotations work for Spring Cloud Components.

For example EnableEuekaClient, EnableEuekaServer, and many more ...

For this purpose i implemented some monitoring components which can be included in the applications. For now all the Beans and Configurations, Controller are read automatically and are straigth forward working.

But I want to enable this whole stuff with an annotation EnableMonitorServer, EnableMonitorClient, EnableMonitorDashboard so they are not automatically loaded and i have to specify which component should be loaded.

I read already some stuff about https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/04/spring-enable-annotation-writing-a-custom-enable-annotation.html, i understand to expose beans on Configuration, but for me it is much more than a Bean.

My example can be found here https://github.com/alwasdev/spring-cloud-monitor, and this will be the repository in which i want to implement the Enable* Annotations.

Please help me with some code examples, or better tutorials, where i can learn how i can disable Controllers, by the annotations, so they only available after i used the Enable* annotation.

Thank you for help and your time.

Greets 
alwasdev

Comment: Did you examine the source code for those annotations? It's pretty clear once you read it.

Comment: I am trying to read this stuff, but i do not get the point where it is turned on/off. I think i do not see some little point, whch is necessary. Maybe someone can point me to the code where it is done. I think of: if(Annotation == Enable*){ loadControllers(), loadConfigs()}

Comment: Did you read *the annotation definition itself*?

Comment: Chrylis, thank you for your help, i fixed the problem by using the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter. I don't know if it is the way to go, but till someone can show me a better way, it is the one i will use.